# Why List(Of T) doesn't have Count()?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, extension-methods

```
Public Class MyList
    Inherits List(Of MyObject)

    Public ReadOnly Property SelectedCount() As Integer
        Get
            Return Me.Count(Function(obj) obj.IsSelected)
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

The above code causes a compile-time error. As you can see, I'm trying to use extension method `Count(<predicate>)`. I guess the error is because there is a similarly-named property Count in `List` class itself too, hiding the extension member.

My questions here are:

1. Do I need to explicitly cast my class to something else to access `Count` extension method? If so, exactly which class should it be in the above scenario?
2. Why can't the compiler infer from the usage that I'm referring to a method and not a property?
3. Does casting involve significant overhead considering that this is a heavily used method (may at times be called hundreds of times a second)?
4. Is C# any better than VB.NET in this regard?

I'm using .NET 4.0 with VS2010 if that has something to do.

**EDIT**

Error message:

> '`Public ReadOnly Property Count As Integer`' has no parameters  and its
>   return type cannot be indexed.

Comment: It causes a compile time error, but you never say what the error said. Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18743457/edit) your question to include the details, people should not need to read comments to see all of the information. At first glance I bet you don't have the `System.Linq` namespace included, but I don't know VB.NET that well, just C#.

Comment: 'Public ReadOnly Property Count As Integer' has no parameters and its return type cannot be indexed.

Comment: Answer of Question #1: Directly call Count() method via Enumerable.Count()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call the method without the extension method syntax:

```
Public Class MyList
    Inherits List(Of MyObject)

    Public ReadOnly Property SelectedCount() As Integer
        Get
            Return Enumerable.Count(Me, Function(obj) obj.IsSelected)
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Make sure you have added an import to System.Linq.

Comment: hmm... Are you also suggesting that even the extension method would internally be calling `Enumerable.Count()`?

Comment: The extension method syntax is just syntactic sugar.  You can also call them this way as an alternative to the extension method syntax.

Comment: @dotNET: No. Extension methods are merely syntactic sugar. `Me.Count(<predicate>)` is changed to `Enumerable.Count(Me, <predicate>)` by the compiler.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Thanks, though I think your comment should have started with 'yes', not 'no'. :)

Comment: @Dan: Thanks Dan. That's some neat help.

Comment: @dotNET: I disagree. The extension method doesn't *internally call* `Enumerable.Count`. The extension method *is* `Enumerable.Count`.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: aah...I see. That's a whole lot of help. I just saw the big picture with the help of that one comment.

Comment: Looking through all the answers, I find this one better in a few respects. It actually suggests a method that is precisely equal to calling the `Count()` extension method, means no performance penalty at all. It also essentially eliminates the need of other 3 questions I asked.

Answer (score 5):

1. You can cast `Me` to `IEnumerable(Of MyObject)`:

   ```
   Return DirectCast(Me, IEnumerable(Of MyObject)).Count(Function(obj) obj.IsSelected)
   ```

   Or use `Enumerable.Count()` method directly:

   ```
   Return Enumerable.Count(Me, Function(obj) obj.IsSelected)
   ```

   Extension Methods are transformed by compiler into direct static (`shared` in VB) methods calls, so there is no difference.
2. Have no idea, really.
3. Casting to underlying type does not change the object itself, so there is no performance penalty (unless `boxing` is involved, what is not a case here).
4. C# does not allow properties with parameters and it requires properties to be called without `()`, so yes, it's better in situations like this one.

   In VB.NET both `Me.Count()` and `Me.Count` refer to `Count` property of `List(Of T`). In C# `this.Count` would refer to property and `this.Count()` would refer the extension method (because of parentheses).

Answer (score 5):

Use AsEnumerable for this purpose:

```
Public ReadOnly Property SelectedCount() As Integer
    Get
        Return Me.AsEnumerable.Count(Function(obj) obj.IsSelected)
    End Get
End Property
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer #4, this works fine in C#:

```cs
public class MyObject { public bool IsSelected { get { return true; } } }

public class MyList : List<MyObject>
{
    public int SelectedCount
    {
        get { return this.Count(x => x.IsSelected); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, confirmed that as well. I really do not like the lambda/LINQ syntax for VB.NET.