# Can't use .Count() from LINQ on Dictionary

Tags: vb.net, linq, dictionary, overloading

When I try the following in VB.NET

```
Dim data = New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
data.Count(Function(x) x.Value > 0) 'Compile-time error!
```

I get this compile error with [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FW0wpC):

> Too many arguments to 'Public Overloads ReadOnly Property Count As Integer'

Visual Studio gives me this error:

> 'Public ReadOnly Property Count As Integer' has no parameters and its return type cannot be indexed.

The following does work though:

```
Enumerable.Where(data, Function(x) x.Value > 0).Count() 'Works!
data.Where(Function(x) x.Value > 0).Count() 'Works!
```

It seems to not be finding the correct overload.

Oddly, enough the C# version of this works just fine in Visual Studio (but fails in .NET Fiddle - odd... what's going on?):

```
var data = new Dictionary<string, int>();
data.Count(x => x.Value > 0);
```

---

What's the correct way to use the LINQ version of `.Count()` [with a predicate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb535181(v=vs.100).aspx) against a dictionary?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18743457/945456

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use [`AsEnumerable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (see the Remarks section) to pick up the extension methods when the names clash.

```
data.AsEnumerable().Count(Function(x) x.Value > 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

There is however a reason why in `VB.NET` it works differently from `C#`:

> When an in-scope instance method has a signature that is compatible with the arguments of a calling statement, the instance method is chosen in preference to any extension method. **The instance method has precedence even if the extension method is a better match.**

and even

> The situation is simpler with properties: **if an extension method has the same name as a property of the class it extends, the extension method is not visible and cannot be accessed**.

a [`Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) already has a property named [`Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhcy256f(v=vs.110).aspx) so the `Count` extension is hidden.

[Extension Methods (Visual Basic) > Extension Methods, Instance Methods, and Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx)

*I'll skip the how-part because @Mark's already answerd that.*

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Wish I had a `Partial Class Answer` I could award to both of y'all ;)