# ContainsValue with Dictionary(Of String, Items)

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, contains

How to know if a dictionary with multiple values contains specific value?

```
'Create dictionary
Dim testDictionary As New Dictionary(Of String, Items)

'Code to fill dictionary
'.......................
'.......................
'.......................

'Test if a specific value is contained in dictionary
Dim testValue as String = "TEST"
testDictionary.ContainsValue(testValue) 'This doesn't work

Public Class Items
    Public Property Property1 As String
    Public Property Property2 As String
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You should use the Key to determine whether a Dictionary contains a specific Value, which, in this case, is also the Property value of a class object. What are you using the Key for? Anyway, you can inspect the Values collection, e.g., `Dim theItem = testDictionary.Values.OfType(Of Items).FirstOrDefault(Function(i) i.Property1.Equals("TEST") OrElse i.Property2.Equals("TEST"))`. You can use `Any()` instead of `FirstOrDefault()` if you just need to test for existence. You should use the Key. Or another type of collection.

Comment: What value? That's a string but the dictionary contains `Items`s. Should the testValue appear in Property1 or Property2? Or either? Or something different altogether?

Comment: If you're looking for values (rather than keys) in a `Dictionary` then you should give serious thought to whether a plain `Dictionary` is the right data structure.  (It may be that ultimately you conclude it is, but searching the values is a giant red flag.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can define how to determine whether the dictionary contains that string, pass that logic into [Enumerable.Any](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8)

```vb
Dim testValue As String = "TEST"

Dim contains = testDictionary.Any(Function(kvp) kvp.Value.Property1 = testValue OrElse kvp.Value.Property2 = testValue)
If contains Then
    Dim containsEntries = testDictionary.Where(Function(kvp) kvp.Value.Property1 = testValue OrElse kvp.Value.Property2 = testValue)
End If
```

Since you reuse it for Any and Where, you can declare the predicate once

```vb
Dim predicate =
    Function(kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, Items))
        Return kvp.Value.Property1 = testValue OrElse kvp.Value.Property2 = testValue
    End Function
Dim contains = testDictionary.Any(predicate)
If contains Then
    Dim containsEntries = testDictionary.Where(predicate)
End If
```

This is hard-coded to just these properties Property1 and Property2.

(you really don't need the Any if you want the entities; I just figured the Any answered your question `"How to know if..."` with a boolean)

If you want to check all public instance string properties, you can use reflection

```vb
Dim predicate =
    Function(kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, Items))
        Return GetType(Items).
            GetProperties(Reflection.BindingFlags.Public Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance).
            Where(Function(pi) pi.PropertyType Is GetType(String)).
            Aggregate(False, Function(pi1, pi2) pi1 Or (pi2.GetValue(kvp.Value) = testValue))
    End Function
Dim containsWith = testDictionary.Any(predicate)
If containsWith Then
    Dim containsEntries = testDictionary.Where(predicate)
End If
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @djv. This is perfect. Just one more question: containsEntries type is IEnumerable, how to get the number of elements it have? I found that IEnumerable doesn't support Count property. To use Count property an ICollection type is necessary but this will generate an error with the Where extension.

Comment: @Queeng4 [it certainly does](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=netframework-4.8). Here is an [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Count__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__) which takes a predicate. In fact, the same predicate I gave you will work. `testDictionary.Count(predicate)` or `containsEntries.Count()`

Comment: Is it necessary to do any Imports? I couldn't get the quantity of elements with containsEntries.Count() due to Count not appear as a property for that object.

Comment: Sorry, this is a VB.NET issue. Try `testDictionary.AsEnumerable().Count(predicate)`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27932993/832052). Basically VB.NET can't distinguish between the Count property and the Enumerable.Count extension. This wouldn't happen in C#. My previous comment was untested and wrong :/

Comment: Okay, no problem. It works now with that tip. I will vote up your answer as correct. I expected less information than what you provided me. Very useful. Thanks again.